# Error with ORDER BY used with HAVING Clause

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, having-clause

I am trying to use some basic SQL functions. I need to get an average of some data and order it in descending order. The error I get is "group function is not allowed"

Table:

```
STUDENTS
-----------
ID
CLASS
GRADE
ROOM
```

SQL:

```
    SELECT ID, class, AVG(Grade) AS AvgGrade
      FROM Students
     GROUP BY AVG(Grade)
    HAVING AVG(Grade) >= 3.0
     ORDER BY AVG(Grade) DESC
```

I was told that ORDER BY cannot be used with the HAVING clause and I would need to repeat the function. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GROUP BY avg(Grade)` doesn't make any sense.

The `GROUP BY` expression defines the groups that you want the aggregate applied to.

Presumably you need `GROUP BY ID, class`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have `avg(Grade)` under `GROUP BY`.

In your example, you'd have to have: `GROUP BY ID, class`.

Answer (score 0):

In Standard SQL, only `AS` clauses ("column aliases") from the `SELECT` clause are allowed in the `ORDER BY` clause i.e.

```
SELECT ID, class, AVG(Grade) AS AvgGrade
  FROM Students
 GROUP BY ID, class
HAVING AVG(Grade) >= 3.0
 ORDER BY AvgGrade DESC;
```

Not all SQL products faithfully implement Standards, of course, but the above should work in SQL Server, for example.